# Power BI DAX: sum different columns based on row value

Tags: dax, left-join, row, multiple-columns, missing-data

I have two tables: A and B. A has one column [cat]. B has 3 columns: [cat], [amount], and [fringe]. A[cat] has 3 values: "Fringe", "Salary", and "Other". B[cat] only has 2 distinct values: "Salary" and "Other". There's a one to many relationship between A[cat] and B[cat].

I would like to have a matrix visual using A[cat] as the rows, and displaying values based on the row value. Specifically, when A[cat]="Fringe", the value is sum(B[Fringe]); when A[cat]<>'Fringe", the value is sum(B[Amount]).

Table A:

| **Cat** |
| --- |
| Fringe |
| Salary |
| Other |

Table B:

| **Cat** | **Amount** | **Fringe** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Salary | 500 | 50 |
| Salary | 600 | 60 |
| Other | 100 | 0 |
| Other | 150 | 0 |

Desired matrix visual:

| **Cat** | **Value ** |
| --- | --- |
| Fringe | 110 |
| Salary | 1100 |
| Other | 250 |

I tried using the following DAX for a new measure, but the matrix rows only shows distinct values of B[cat], missing "Fringe".

```
DAX code of new measure:
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        ALL(A[cat]),
        SWITCH(
            TRUE(),
            A[cat] = "Fringe", CALCULATE(SUM('B'[Fringe])),
            A[cat] <> "Fringe", CALCULATE(SUM('B'[Amount]))
        )
    )
)
```

matrix visual:

| **Cat** | **Value ** |
| --- | --- |
| Salary | 1100 |
| Other | 250 |

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get `ALL` rows for `Fringe`.

```
CALCULATE(SUM('B'[Fringe]), ALL('B'))
```